# Symfony2 orm custom query issue

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine

i'm stuck with a Doctrine ORM query error, i'm sure its a very simple fix but i dont understand everything yet in symfony2 :) i made hours of searches but cannot find the solution by myself.

```
Notice: Undefined index: id_chapter in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib
\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 93

Notice: Undefined index: id_book in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib
\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 93

Notice: Undefined index: id_testament in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib
\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 93

Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\
Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 2433

Notice: Undefined index: id_chapter in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\
Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 366

Notice: Undefined index: id_chapter in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib
\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator.php on line 367

Fatal error: Call to a member function getValue() on a non-object in C:\xampp\
htdocs\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator
.php on line 371
```

It seems that those notices reffers to a mapping mistake from me, here a part of my entity build

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="testament", inversedBy="books")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_testament", referencedColumnName="id_testament")
 */
 protected $testament;
```

ask for more detail if needed, any help will be much apreciated! thx.

edit: it might be useful to add this piece of code

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);
        $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('dieuenligne\websiteBundle\Entity\line', 'l');
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('dieuenligne\websiteBundle\Entity\livreChapitre', 'c', 'l', 'id_chapter', array('id_chapter' => 'idc'));
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('dieuenligne\websiteBundle\Entity\book', 'b', 'c', 'id_book', array('id_book' => 'idb'));
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('dieuenligne\websiteBundle\Entity\testament', 't', 'b', 'id_testament', array('id_testament' => 'idt'));

        $sql = 'SELECT t.id_testament, b.book_number, c.chapter_wording, l.line_number, l.line_content FROM line l INNER JOIN chapter c ON l.id_chapter = c.id_chapter 
                    INNER JOIN book b ON c.id_book = b.id_book 
                    INNER JOIN testament t ON b.id_testament = t.id_testament 
                    WHERE MATCH (line_content) AGAINST (:request) LIMIT 0,75';

        $query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql, $rsm);
        $query->setParameter('request', $request);

        $lines = $query->getResult();
```

---

This is my new code, working on the id conflict problem:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $rsm = new ResultSetMappingBuilder($em);
        $rsm->addRootEntityFromClassMetadata('dieuenligne\websiteBundle\Entity\line', 'l', array('id' => 'lid'));
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('dieuenligne\websiteBundle\Entity\livreChapitre', 'c', 'l', 'id_chapter', array('id_chapter' => 'idc'));
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('dieuenligne\websiteBundle\Entity\book', 'b', 'c', 'id_book', array('id_book' => 'idb'));
        $rsm->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata('dieuenligne\websiteBundle\Entity\testament', 't', 'b', 'id_testament', array('id_testament' => 'idt'));

$sql = 'SELECT t.id, b.book_number, c.chapter_wording, l.line_number, l.line_content FROM line l INNER JOIN chapter c ON l.id_chapter = c.id 
                    INNER JOIN book b ON c.id_book = b.id 
                    INNER JOIN testament t ON b.id_testament = t.id 
                    WHERE MATCH (line_content) AGAINST (:request) LIMIT 0,75';
```

Here is a part of my testament entity:

```
class testament
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id_bible", type="integer").
 */
private $idBible;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="testament_wording", type="string", length=20)
 */
private $testamentWording;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="bible", inversedBy="testaments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_bible", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $bible;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="book", mappedBy="testament")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"bookNumber" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $books;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->books = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

This is my error:

```
The column 'id' conflicts with another column in the mapper. 

at ResultSetMappingBuilder ->addAllClassFields ('dieuenligne\websiteBundle\Entity\book', 'b', array('id_book' => 'idb'))
in C:\xampp\htdocs\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder.php at line 71  +
at ResultSetMappingBuilder ->addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata ('dieuenligne\websiteBundle\Entity\book', 'b', 'c', 'id_book', array('id_book' => 'idb'))
in C:\xampp\htdocs\src\dieuenligne\websiteBundle\Controller\WebsiteController.php at line 112  +
```

I'm working on it, and I'll update if solved. I had this error before, and I added the  `array('id_chapter' => 'idc')` in the `addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata`, but it seems not to be the solution here.

I didn't find a solution in the doc. I respected most of the conventions, but I still have a id issue (seems to be that).

Should I show a bigger part of my code?

EDIT

Still stucked on this, here is the code in the `ResultSetMappingBuilder.php at line 71`

```
public function addJoinedEntityFromClassMetadata($class, $alias, $parentAlias, $relation, $renamedColumns = array())
{
    $this->addJoinedEntityResult($class, $alias, $parentAlias, $relation);
    $this->addAllClassFields($class, $alias, $renamedColumns);
}
```

the line 71 is on the `addAllClassFields`. To me, the class, the alias and the renamedColumns are just fine and since i'm using the renamedColumns attribute (`array('id_book' => 'idb')`) i shouldn't have an id conflict...

Thanks in advance for any advices on this, it is my first project on symfony as well as being a beginner in web developpment, so i really need help on this! :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure because i haven't see other part of your code, but if your entity named `Testament` and referencedColumnName is `id` than:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Testament", inversedBy="books")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_testament", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
 protected $testament;
```

Comment: i modified my database so instead of having "id_testament" for my table testament i have now "id". The entity has been changed too so all the referencedColumnName are id now.

I'm having an 500 error: The column 'id' conflicts with another column in the mapper.

Comment: @user2841678 Why do you have 2 `id_bible` in one entity?

Comment: $idBible is my foreign key, i may have make a mistake here? i followed a french tutorial where he join the tables with another argument (here $bible).

Comment: @user2841678 try to use [doctrine doc](https://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html). And try to use some code coventions (for example name classes by uppercase first letter). Than you can read your code without some difficultes.